# HttpServletRequest.getInputStream() does not unwrap chunked HTTP request

Tags: java, http, tomcat

I am in the process of sending a HTTP chunked request to an internal system.  I've confirmed other factors are not at play by ensuring that I can send small messages without chunk encoding.

My process was basically to change the `Transfer-Encoding` header to be `chunked` and I've removed the `Content-Length` header.  Additionally, I am utilising an in-house `ChunkedOutputStream` which has been around for quite some time.

I am able to connect, obtain an output stream and send the data.  The recipient then returns a `200` response so it seems the request was received and successfully handled.  The endpoint receives the HTTP Request, and streams the data straight into a table (using `HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()`).

On inspecting the streamed data I can see that the chunk encoding information in the stream has not been unwrapped/decoded by the Tomcat container automatically.  I've been trawling the Tomcat `HTTPConnector` documentation and can't find anything that alludes to the chunked encoding w.r.t how a chunk encoded message should be handled within a `HttpServlet`.  I can't see other StackOverflow questions querying this so I suspect I am missing something basic.

My question boils down to:

- Should Tomcat automatically decode the chunked encoding from my request and give me a "clean" `InputStream` when I call `HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()`?
- If yes, is there configuration that needs to be updated to enable this functionality?  Am I sending something wrong in the headers that is causing it to return the non-decoded stream?
- If no, is it common practice to wrap input stream in a [ChunkedInputStream](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/ChunkedInputStream.html) or something similar when the `Transfer-Encoding` header is present ?

Answer (score 1):

This is solved.  As expected it was basic in my case.

The legacy system I was using provided handrolled methods to simplify the process of opening a HTTP Connection, sending headers and then using an OutputStream to send the content via a POST.  I didn't realise, and it was in a rather obscure location, but the behind-the-scenes helper's we're identifying that I was *not* specifying a `Content-Length` thus added the `TRANSFER_ENCODING=chunked` header and wrapped the OutputStream in a `ChunkedOutputStream`.  This resulted in me double encoding the contents, hence my endpoints (seeming) inability to decode it.

Case closed.

Comment: They should have used `HttpURLConnection`. It already has chunking built in. I don't know why people keep reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Completely agree.  Really it was a plain oversight on my part.  The legacy system is 15+ years old so I am not surprised things are suboptimal there, still, I should have noticed.